# How to find android tablet support for phone calling or not?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application for both phone's and tablets.There is a problem with tablets.Some tablets are having calling to phone number function.Here i should know which tablets contains phone calling function and which don't have that function.Please advice me how to find which tablet have phone calling function and which one not supported.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this snippet to determine whether or not the device has the Telephony feature:

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
    // You can make calls
} else {
    // You can't make calls
}
```

Beyond that, if you simply want to make sure that your app isn't installed on any device without the ability to make calls, add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:required="true"
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
```

Please remember that `android.hardware.telephony` is an umbrella feature, and some tablets may implement sub parts of it, like `android.hardware.telephony.cdma` or `android.hardware.telephony.gsm`

Comment: at this point setting that to "true" will severely limit the penetration of your app in the play store

Comment: Which is why I said `if you simply want to make sure that your app isn't installed on any device without the ability to make calls`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have one more clarification also.My app should show for mobile version and tablet version. I will make two apk files to upload into market like MyApp_phone.apk, MyApp_tablet.apk.Here i want to prevent mobile version in tablets google play list and prevent tablet version in mobile. how can i do this please advice me. Thank you.

Comment: That functionality isn't supported by Google Play

Answer (score 4):

in your android manifest, set

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

and then set

```
if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
// Device supports calling
} else {
  // No phone calling support
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet

```
if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
    // Device supports calling
} else {
    // No phone calling support
}
```